# WCF client unable to receive object

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I am using nettcp binding, and sending an object successfully on the WCF service, but unable to receive the response (containing return type of same object) and get following error:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:02:59.9990000'.
>       System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException

Did someone encounter same problem as I did? Any help will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried changing the timeouts? 3 minutes would sound normal, but if your data is that big its taking longer...

Comment: I tried returning an integer, but was unable to do so as well, initially timeout was 40 minutes (was receiving same error).

Comment: Then Id suggest a minimal viable reproducable code is needed

Comment: The error is around when object returns, I tried returning empty object i.e. new object and it was successful, but whenever object is filled with data, this error occurs..

Comment: going to need to see code - WCF works for so many in so many places, no one can help you without seeing something more

Comment: Could you share your code? Anyway, this issue can be related with serialize problems, try to inspect if the object you're returning can be serialized. You can try to test your service with wcf test client tool.

Comment: There are objects within this returning object and all are decorated with [Serializable] attribute. I am sending same class's object in parameter which is successfully being received at WCF service, why can't response instance of same class's object be returned?

Comment: @BugFinder I resolved it by decorating my data contract with KnownType attribute for the object that was not serializing successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried changing WCF binding from **nettcp to http**, but that only changed the error I was receiving i.e.,

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response .. This could be
>   due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This
>   could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the
>   server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs
>   for more details.

As it mentioned "See server logs for more details", I reviewed WCF logs and noted that an error occurred while serializing an object, I decorated the class of that object with **KnownType** attribute on my DataContract, and it worked.